# Value of $f^2(4)+g^2(4)$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

If $f(x)=g'(x),g(x)=-f'(x)$ for all real $x$ and $f(2)=4=f'(2)$ then value of $f^2(4)+g^2(4)$ is ? Now the above is true when we have a  constant function with constant $0$. But then that would not satisfy third condition ?what can this function be? Thanks !

Comment: We can show $$f(x)=a\cos x+b\sin x$$

Comment: But. How will one get value of $\cos(2),\sin(2)$ without calculator

Comment: Hint:  let $H(x)=f^2(x)+g^2(x)$ and prove that $H'(x)=0$

Answer (score 1):

HINT, using Laplace transform:

$$
\begin{cases}
f(x)=g'(x)\\
g(x)=-f'(x)
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
\text{F}(s)=s\text{G}(s)-g(0)\\
\text{G}(s)=f(0)-s\text{F}(s)
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
\text{F}(s)=s\text{G}(s)-g(0)\\
\text{G}(s)=f(0)-s\text{F}(s)
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
\text{F}(s)=\frac{sf(0)-g(0)}{1+s^2}\\
\text{G}(s)=\frac{f(0)+sg(0)}{1+s^2}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, with inverse Laplace transform:

- $$f(x)=f(0)\cos(x)-g(0)\sin(x)$$
- $$g(x)=g(0)\cos(x)+f(0)\sin(x)$$

Using the initial conditions to find $f(0)$ and $g(0)$:

$$
\begin{cases}
4=f(0)\cos(2)-g(0)\sin(2)\\
4=-g(0)\cos(2)-f(0)\sin(2)
\end{cases}
$$

So: $f(0)=4(\cos(2)-\sin(2))$ and $g(0)=-4(\sin(2)+\cos(2))$

So:

$$f(4)^2+g(4)^2=32$$

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to solve for $f$ and $g$.

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} (f^2 + g^2) = 2 f f' + 2 g g' = -2 f g + 2 g f = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $f(x)=g'(x)$, and $g(x)=-f'(x)$, we have that $g'(x)=-f''(x)$, so $f(x)=-f''(x)$.  This is a differential equation, with a well-known solution (namely, $f(x)=A\sin x+B\cos x$.  The condition $f(2)=4\implies A\sin 2+B\cos 2=4$, and $f'(2)=4\implies A\cos 2-B\sin 2=4$.  Subtracting these two expressions, we get that $(A-B)\sin 2-(A-B)\cos 2=0\implies (A-B)(\sin 2-\cos 2)=0$.  From this, we see that $A-B=0$, so $A=B$.

So, we have that $f(x)=A(\sin x+\cos x)$, and thus $f(2)=4\implies A=\frac{4}{\sin 2+\cos 2}$.  So, $f(x)=\frac{4}{\sin 2+\cos 2}(\sin x+\cos x)$, and thus the last step can be computed directly (I would, I just don't know if $f^2(x)=f(f(x))$ or $f^2(x)=(f(x))^2$ here).